# Javascript How to split string by symbols count

Tags: javascript

I have few strings 'ABCDEF', 'GHIJKL' ...
I need to split them by 3 and 3 symbols to array.

```
var str = 'ABCDEF';
str.split(3)
// need return array('ABC','DEF');
```

Is ther a way to do it beautifully?